# Exiting an app when an error is thrown without showing the stack trace on screen

Tags: nativescript

How can I stop nativescript from showing the error stack trace on the screen ? Stack trace is really helpful for developer, but just in case, some edge cases are not covered for the app afterrelease, and an unexpected error occurs, it would be bad experience for the user to see the stack trace. Is there a way to throw out of the App in android and iOS both?

try catch statements do work, but not in all cases, for example when the memory is low and all downloaded and cached images are purged, lowMemory error is thrown and stack is visible on screen.

Comment: Are you sure this occurs on Android in a --release app; I thought the error stack code was disabled in release mode.

Comment: Never tried release flag, let me try it

Comment: @Nathanael , yes you were right, it does not occur in the release app, is the same behavior true for the iOS, can you please write it as an answer so I can select it as a correct one, just as a lookup for people facing same issue - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an android application is built in release mode;

**tns build android --release --key-store-path [path] --key-store-password [pw] --key-store-alias [alias] --key-store-alias-pw [pw]**

The app will automatically disable the stack trace screen on Android.   By default the **tns build android** will be building debug mode applications.